# Local fuzzy select in GIMP

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to be able to draw a select rectangle and then use the fuzzy select tool so that it will only expand to that rectangle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click the fuzzy selection tool to open its options. Set mode "intersect" ON. The fuzzy selection is limited to the previously selected area.

[image]

BTW. Learn the rest of the options in GIMP user's guide. They are all as important.

Answer (score 0):

The method by @user287001 works but if you mis-click you lose the selection. A less stressful way is to

- do the first selection,
- save it to a channel (`Select ➤ Save to channel`)
- do the second selection
- open the Channels list
- right click the saved selection
- use the appropriate operation (Intersect/Add/Subtract)

Saving selection to channels also lets you combine them in different ways